# Create Dynamic List From Radio Button Select

Tags: php, html

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I've put together the code below to try and allow a user to retrieve mySQL records via a radio button select, in turn populating a table on my html form.

**Form**

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(name)
{
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getrecords.php?dateoftrip="+name,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getquerystring() {
var form = document.forms['frm1'];
var word = form.word.value;
qstr = 'w=' + escape(word); // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
return qstr;
}


</script>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="getrecords.php" method="get" name="frm1">

<table width="148" border="0">

<tr>
<td width="152"><p class="style1">Select a date from below</p>
  <div align="center">
    <?php
include("db.php");
$query="select userid, dateoftrip from finds group by dateoftrip";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while (list($userid, $dateoftrip) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     '<td><input type='radio' name='name' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"/></td>\n'
    .'<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n'
    .'</tr>\n'
  }
  echo"<tr><td colspan=\"3\">";
  echo"<br>";
  echo"</td></tr>";
  echo'</table>';

?>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**getrecords.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$dateoftrip= $_GET['dateoftrip'];
$findname= $_GET['findname'];
$finddescription= $_GET['finddescription'];

$query="select * from finds where dateoftrip='$dateoftrip'";
echo "<table>";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Find Name : </td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['findname']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Find Description : </td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['finddescription']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The problem I'm having is that I receive the following error and I'm not sure why: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/ajaxfunction.php on line 69` with line 69 being this line of my html form code:
`'<td><input type='radio' name='name' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"/></td>\n'`

I've been working on this for a while and so far I've unsuccessful at resolving it. I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to this

```
 echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     "<td><input type='radio' name='name' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' onchange="."ajaxFunction(this.value)"."/></td>\n"
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply. I've now got rid of the error message, but unfortunately I can't create the table with the retrieved records. Could you tell me please have you any ideas where I may be going wrong? Many thanks

Comment: and what error do you have on creating the table? showing nothing or ?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't receive any error. I've enclosed a link to my page to highlight this a little better. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/ajaxfunction.php Kind regards

Comment: you have there two times </table> , delete the first one

Comment: Hi, many thansk for this. I've made the change but unfortunately I still can't get the records from the 'getrecords.php' script. Kind regards

Comment: so there's problem in your javascript code, do alert(xmlhttp.responseText); and see if there's something showed or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8759/discussion-between-irhm-and-riso)

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is messed up on that line. Use double-quotes for the outer string, so variables get interpolated, and escape characters like `\n` are not interpreted as literals.

echo"\n"
    .
     "\n"
    ."{$dateoftrip}\n"
    ."\n";
    //------^^^^ Missing semicolon....

You can also accomplish this more cleanly with a [`HEREDOC` statement,](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and avoid the quoting issue and linebreks entirely:

```
  echo <<<HTML
    <tr>
    <td><input type='radio' name='name' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' onchange='ajaxFunction(this.value)'/></td>
    <td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>
    </tr>
HTML;
```

A further note: your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Escape all your input values with `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
$dateoftrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['dateoftrip']);
$findname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['findname']);
$finddescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['finddescription']);
// etc...
```

Comment: There's also a missing semi-colon on that line in the OP's code.

Comment: @jprofitt Thanks Noted above. That's why I advocate for HEREDOCs instead of multi-line concatenations...

Comment: Hi, HEREDOCs are certainly new to me, I'll have to take a look at these. And duly notes about the SQL Injection. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape those quotes and add a semi-colon at the end of the echo statement.

```
echo "<tr>\n <td><input type='radio' name='name' dateoftrip value='$userid' onchange=\"ajaxFunction(this.value)\"/></td>\n <td><small>$dateoftrip</small><td>\n</tr>\n";
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. As above thankfully I've now been able to get rid of the error message, but I'm unfortunately unable to create the table with the retrieved results. Kind regards